# Validation framework not working after struts upgrade

Tags: struts2, struts-validation

We recently upgraded struts from 2.2.1 to 2.3.34. After the upgrade, however the validation framework is not working. Getting the following exception.

```
    07:04:58,974 ERROR [CommonsLogger.error] -  -  - Caught exception while loading file com/project/actions/RegistrationAction-register-validation.xml
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.AnnotationActionValidatorManager.loadFile(AnnotationActionValidatorManager.java:397)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.AnnotationActionValidatorManager.buildAliasValidatorConfigs(AnnotationActionValidatorManager.java:274)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.AnnotationActionValidatorManager.buildValidatorConfigs(AnnotationActionValidatorManager.java:377)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.AnnotationActionValidatorManager.getValidators(AnnotationActionValidatorManager.java:101)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.AnnotationActionValidatorManager.validate(AnnotationActionValidatorManager.java:140)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.AnnotationActionValidatorManager.validate(AnnotationActionValidatorManager.java:132)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.AnnotationActionValidatorManager.validate(AnnotationActionValidatorManager.java:127)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doBeforeInvocation(ValidationInterceptor.java:222)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:263)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:76)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:229)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:229)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.DateTextFieldInterceptor.intercept(DateTextFieldInterceptor.java:125)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:253)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:140)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:189)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
at com.umonitor.fundstransfer6.interceptors.FtPostOnlyInterceptor.intercept(FtPostOnlyInterceptor.java:32)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:575)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:81)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
at com.umonitor.fundstransfer6.filter.DPXPayFilter.doFilter(DPXPayFilter.java:67)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at com.umonitor.server.headers.CustomHeaderModifier.doFilter(CustomHeaderModifier.java:45)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:470)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:615)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:620)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Also getting the following exception

```
   07:36:37,404 WARN  [CommonsLogger.warn] -  -  - Unable to load config class org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor at interceptor - jar:file:/home/tomcat/lib/struts2-core-2.3.34.jar!/struts-default.xml:217:127 probably due to a missing jar, which might be fine if you never plan to use the validation interceptor
07:36:37,404 ERROR [CommonsLogger.error] -  -  - Actual exception
Caught Exception while registering Interceptor class org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor - interceptor - jar:file:/home/tomcat/lib/struts2-core-2.3.34.jar!/struts-default.xml:217:127
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.factory.DefaultInterceptorFactory.buildInterceptor(DefaultInterceptorFactory.java:64)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildInterceptor(ObjectFactory.java:209)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.InterceptorBuilder.constructInterceptorReference(InterceptorBuilder.java:70)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.lookupInterceptorReference(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:1114)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadInterceptorStack(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:932)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadInterceptorStacks(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:945)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadInterceptors(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:968)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addPackage(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:537)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:295)
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:112)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:264)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.getContainer(Dispatcher.java:978)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:446)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:490)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:57)
    at com.umonitor.fundstransfer6.filter.DPXPayFilter.init(DPXPayFilter.java:40)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:298)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4076)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4730)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:802)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:583)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:943)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:778)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1385)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:306)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1392)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1656)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1665)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1645)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MethodInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:301)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:492)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$6.call(ContainerImpl.java:530)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$6.call(ContainerImpl.java:528)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.callInContext(ContainerImpl.java:584)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:528)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.injectInternalBeans(ObjectFactory.java:166)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:191)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:178)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.factory.DefaultInterceptorFactory.buildInterceptor(DefaultInterceptorFactory.java:42)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$4.create(ContainerBuilder.java:132)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.Scope$2$1.create(Scope.java:51)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$ParameterInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:469)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.getParameters(ContainerImpl.java:484)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.access$000(ContainerImpl.java:34)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MethodInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:299)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:502)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$7.call(ContainerImpl.java:539)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.callInContext(ContainerImpl.java:593)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:537)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.LocatableFactory.create(LocatableFactory.java:32)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$4.create(ContainerBuilder.java:130)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MethodInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:301)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$ConstructorInjector.construct(ContainerImpl.java:438)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:499)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$4.create(ContainerBuilder.java:132)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.Scope$2$1.create(Scope.java:51)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$ParameterInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:469)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.getParameters(ContainerImpl.java:484)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.access$000(ContainerImpl.java:34)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MethodInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:299)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:502)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$7.call(ContainerImpl.java:539)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.callInContext(ContainerImpl.java:593)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:537)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.LocatableFactory.create(LocatableFactory.java:32)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$4.create(ContainerBuilder.java:130)
    ... 61 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$ConstructorInjector.construct(ContainerImpl.java:447)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:499)
    ... 66 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$ConstructorInjector.construct(ContainerImpl.java:426)
    ... 67 more
Caused by: Connection timed out - [unknown location]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper.parse(DomHelper.java:119)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.DefaultValidatorFileParser.parseValidatorDefinitions(DefaultValidatorFileParser.java:119)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.DefaultValidatorFactory.retrieveValidatorConfiguration(DefaultValidatorFactory.java:201)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.DefaultValidatorFactory.parseValidators(DefaultValidatorFactory.java:190)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.DefaultValidatorFactory.<init>(DefaultValidatorFactory.java:61)
    ... 72 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1004)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:952)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:851)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1301)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.startDTDEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.setInputSource(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:392)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper.parse(DomHelper.java:117)
    ... 76 more
```

The exceptions occur while restarting the tomcat server. The validation framework was working fine in the old version. Please help to resolve this issue.

Comment: please update with full stack traces specially `caused-by`s

Comment: i have updated the question with full stack trace.

Comment: Restarting tomcat server only needed for system changes.

Answer (score 0):

try this `PUBLIC ID`:

```
<!DOCTYPE validators PUBLIC "-//Apache Struts//XWork Validator 1.0.3//EN"
        "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/xwork-validator-1.0.3.dtd">
```

Comment: @DivyaRose, your stack trace shows trying to connect internet which means it cannot find `xwork-validator dtd` in jar files which means `PUBLIC ID` in one or more of your validation xml files is wrong.

Comment: changed my dtds to `<!DOCTYPE validators PUBLIC "-//Apache Struts//XWork Validator 1.0.3//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/xwork-validator-1.0.3.dtd">` and got rid of the second exception. But the first one is still there and validation framework is still not working. It is still showing a null pointer exception while loading file

Comment: So please set devMode to true [1], configure log4j2 and set it's level to WARN [2] then examine output for any related warning.
[1] https://struts.apache.org/docs/devmode.html
[2] Step 4 of https://struts.apache.org/getting-started/how-to-create-a-struts2-web-application.html

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution!!!

We are using classname-method-validation.xml files and a validators.xml file.

In classname-method-validation.xml, give the doc type as below:

```
    <!DOCTYPE validators PUBLIC "-//Apache Struts//XWork Validator 1.0.3//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/xwork-validator-1.0.3.dtd">
```

and in validators.xml, use the below doc type:

```
<!DOCTYPE validators PUBLIC "-//Apache Struts//XWork Validator Definition 1.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/xwork-validator-definition-1.0.dtd">
```

Also, while using regex for validation, we were using the param name as `expression`. It should be changed to `regexExpression`.

eg:

```
<field-validator type="regex" short-circuit="true">
     <param name="regexExpression"><![CDATA[^(?!0{9})(\d{9})$]]>
     </param>
     <message>${getText("ft.accounts.alert.validRoutingNumber")}</message></field-validator>
```